# How do I update in SQL syntax multiple values in the same command MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

What I want to do is update the column productName where the value is ='OpenAM' (there are two in this case) but how about when there are more than just two and by mistake a user inputs the same value to all of them now I have to fix them without having to go one by one.

I tried using the IN operator to solve this or is there a better way and the way I am trying to doing this is completely wrong.

this is my table

```
CREATE TABLE ForgeRock
    (`id` int, `productName` varchar(7), `description` varchar(55))
;

INSERT INTO ForgeRock
    (`id`, `productName`, `description`)
VALUES
    (1, 'OpenIDM', 'Platform for building enterprise provisioning solutions'),
    (2, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management'),
    (3, 'OpenDJ', 'Robust LDAP server for Java'),
    (4, 'OpenAM', 'Full-featured access management2')
;
```

This is what I am trying to do

```
UPDATE ForgeRock
SET
productName='New value'
WHERE IN(
  'OpenAM'
  )
```

Comment: ...where productName='OpenAM' - but be careful, this will update all records where the product name is OpenAM!

Comment: Instead of `WHERE IN` you can just use `WHERE productName = 'OpenAM'`